# Need to update database after exit statement in subroutine

Tags: perl

```
sub Processing {    
.
.
.
.
foreach my $hProc (@{ $hRes->{'List'} }) {
.
.
elsif($hProc->{BATCH_TYPE} =~ /^(abc)$/i) {
            # All is Ok. Need to launch new process.
            if ($pid = fork) { #for parent process
                sleep 1; #wait for child process
                $oLogger->info("process launched.");
                $hActions->{xyz}--;
                AddAction ($id_auth,'Success. Batch process','',undef,undef,$hProc->{SESSION},"$hProc->{BATCH_TYPE} Launched successfully",undef);
                next
            } elsif (defined $pid) { #for child process

                if($hProc->{STATUS} eq 'Not started') {
                my $temp = UpdateProcess( { STATUS=>'In Processing',START_TS=>'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }, { id=>$hProc->{ID} } );
                next unless $temp;
                }
                $cmdStr = join ' ', $scriptName, $Parameters, $Output, '-archiver=gzip';
                $cmdStr .= "; chown $Owner" if $Owner;
                $cmdStr .= "; chmod $Permissions" if $Permissions;

                goToScript("perl $cmdStr >/dev/null 2>>$err_to_file_ecm");

            } else {
                $oLogger->error("!process launch FAILED. FORK could not create child process");
        } 
    }


sub goToScript {
my ($script) = @_;
print "$script\n" if $trace;
exec($script);
exit;
```

Hi All, I want to update status for my db from 'In Processing' to 'Completed' as described above. But the problem is after control going to sub goToScript(), it won't execute any statement afterwards because of 'exit' statement. So, how can i update my db status as 'Completed'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a mess, and you should really not do that `exit` there. If you do `exec` the other program (`$script`) will never return. It just gets started and your program forgets about it. So how can you know that it's *Completed*?

I'd get rid of the `exit`, rename `goToScript` to `startScript` and then do your change after the call to that function.

If you really insist on doing it the way you have it now, you can use an `END` block. That will get called when the program ends, during cleanup. That way, you can update your status. You don't say what you need for it, but I guess you want to call `UpdateProcess`.

```
elsif (defined $pid) { #for child process
    # ...

    END {
        UpdateProcess(
            { STATUS=>'Completed',START_TS=>'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' },
            { id=>$hProc->{ID} }
        );
    }
    goToScript("perl $cmdStr >/dev/null 2>>$err_to_file_ecm");
}
```

You need to define the `END` block in the middle of the code because you need to use the lexically scoped `$hProc` to be available as it holds your  id.

See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END) for more details on `END`.